# jquery post on keyup "Fail[s] to load resource"

Tags: jquery, post, keyup, network-connection

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#team-search").keyup(function() {
    if($("#team-search").val().length > 0) {
      $("#search-results").slideDown(300);
    }
    else {
      $("#search-results").slideUp(300);
    }
    $.post("team-search.php",{team: $("#team-search").val()},function(result) {
      $("#search-results").html(result);
    });
  });
});
```

and everything works; it sends the post request with the `team:$("#team-search")` value and it prints the results into `$("#search-results")`.

but after typing about 20 characters, it stops printing the result and I check the error log and it says this: `[Error] Failed to load resource: The network connection was lost. (team-search.php, line 0)` every time you type a key.

What am I doing wrong? Or what should I fix? Why is this happening?

my network connection is really and everything else works fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely a problem on the server side. Check network tab in developer tools (if you use chrome/safari) to see what's happening with network.

List of the problems that may be the case:

- Network issue, duh
- Wrong server configuration
- Error in PHP script
- Error on the server itself

P.S.: Please specify more details like: the script you use, your browser, your server software and location (local / remote).

Comment: its definitely not a network issue and I'm 99% sure my php works. How would I see if there is a wrong server configuration?

Comment: and I'm using php, Safari is my browser, and its hosted remotely

Comment: @phprunner check your network tab to see what's server returning

Comment: how would I do that? I'm familiar with the developer console, but not the network tab

Comment: @phprunner it's in the developer console, right next to the resources (if you use safari 9, previous version has a slightly different positioning)

Comment: yes i know that, but what am i looking for when you say "see what's server returning"

Comment: @phprunner with the tab opened start typing in #team-search. Network query will pop up in there. Look at it's status. To see what's server returning click at the small arrow in first column.

Comment: the status says 200 until it has the error and the status is "-"

Comment: @phprunner code 200 is okay. looks like your server is rejecting the query, it's definitely wrong configuration

Comment: @phprunner first question: what software do you use? apache? nginx? or IIS on windows?

Comment: I'm pretty sure its apache. but I'm not certain. how can i find out? my files are all hosted on cpanel/godaddy. does that matter?

Comment: @phprunner go, again, to the network tab, click on the small arrow and open the right panel. Scroll to the end. Look at the server header.

Comment: @phprunner if you use godaddy i'm pretty sure they have apache configured to reject fast sequences of queries to prevent DoS attacks. This is your problem.

Comment: is there any way I can get around that?

Comment: @phprunner can you provide a link to the document? I'll try to search and see if I was right about DoS config.

Comment: @phprunner you can try hitting their API using tools like POSTMan/Fiddler to make sure that API is the culprit. Its the best way to test your API.

Comment: @phprunner solutions: 1. change your hoster 2. limit the number of queries in jQuery